# Display blank instead of zero in RadGridView data column

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik

Is there a way to display blank instead of zero values for percents?

This is displayed currently:

[image]

This is the desired display:

[image]

Xaml formatted like this currently:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding pPromoDiscountPct, StringFormat='{}{0:P2}'}" Header="Promo Discount %">
```

I tried several variations of StringFormat but end up with either just a % or nothing at all.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Friend can you try this

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding pPromoDiscountPct, StringFormat='{}{0:#%;#%;}'}" Header="Promo Discount %">
```

What does it mean
{0:PositiveFormate;NegativeFormate;ZeroFormat} Hope it will help you. I kept empty in zero section.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tweaked it a bit and put a # for the zero section.  Otherwise it printed just a % for zero values.  The data is displaying just perfectly now.